# Writing a conditional mean argument

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mean

The following is an example data frame that I am working on:

```
       Age   Exon.1    Exon.2   Exon.3    Exon.4 Tissue
1   8 pcw 1.069621  2.090989 2.815579  2.599460    HIP
2   9 pcw 0.359670  1.327652 0.997034  1.128186    HIP
3  12 pcw 1.170716  7.368116 4.855342  4.868139    HIP
4  12 pcw 0.618367  0.780580 1.564149  2.119555    HIP
5  12 pcw 0.592584  3.233361 1.750408  4.784493    HIP
6  13 pcw 1.634750  3.852918 5.822762  4.215661    HIP
7  13 pcw 1.076103  3.653933 4.616696  4.288468    HIP
8  13 pcw 0.530033  1.572620 1.643339  2.447955    HIP
9  16 pcw 0.607179  6.393372 4.284723  6.054567    HIP
10 16 pcw 1.649528  8.162135 6.258901  5.672448    HIP
11 17 pcw 3.857213  6.297120 2.644501  6.823737    HIP
12 19 pcw 2.025933  2.471025 3.151600  5.400733    HIP
13 21 pcw 3.666728 12.037541 8.605424 11.427137    HIP
14 24 pcw 0.569007  3.611914 2.728669  7.173590    HIP
15 37 pcw 0.153815  0.000000 0.622567  0.606804    HIP
16  4 mos 2.585179  1.980350 3.781297  4.898531    HIP
17  4 mos 0.760953  0.339324 1.501044  2.491687    HIP
18  1 yrs 2.003685  7.804700 8.027769  7.122507    HIP
19  2 yrs 0.000000  0.616036 0.000000  0.050892    HIP
20  3 yrs 0.302567  0.000000 0.000000  0.402933    HIP
21  8 yrs 0.765591  2.332778 1.736967  4.598780    HIP
22  8 yrs 1.157266  3.497623 2.591768  3.543247    HIP
23 11 yrs 0.337816  0.000000 0.000000  3.256239    HIP
24 13 yrs 0.082116  0.000000 0.000000  1.421612    HIP
25 18 yrs 0.243391  0.000000 0.000000  0.601639    HIP
26 19 yrs 0.716598  1.412251 2.421302  4.201108    HIP
27 21 yrs 1.742922  4.678306 3.216452  3.701010    HIP
28 23 yrs 0.158256  0.760269 0.220072  2.115750    HIP
29 30 yrs 1.303604  0.488246 2.493215  3.816740    HIP
30 36 yrs 0.367384  2.611151 2.322208  3.423121    HIP
31 37 yrs 0.643085  3.441538 3.193851  4.546699    HIP
32 40 yrs 0.145881  0.000000 0.000000  1.622436    HIP
```

In R, I want to write an argument that would compute the mean for all rows in Exon.1, only if the row contains the following ages: "4 mos", "1 yrs", "2 yrs", "3 yrs".

I attempted to subset the values for Exon.1 through a series of trial arguments.

```
birth.infant <- c("4 mons", "1 yrs", "2 yrs", "3 yrs")
mean(data.frame$Exon.1 | birth.infant) # error
mean(data.frame$Exon.1 | if(intersect(data.frame$Age, birth.infant) == TRUE))
if(intersect(data.frame$Age, birth.infant)==TRUE) mean(data.frame$Exon.1)
```

If these illustrations aren't clear, my goal is to use `birth.infant` as include certain Exon.1 values of interest for computing a mean.

How might I establish a conditional mean argument for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `mean(Data$Exon.1[which(Data$Age %in% birth.infant)])` ? This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Jealie said,

```
mean(Data$Exon.1[Data$Age %in% birth.infant])
```

except remove the which. It serves no purpose other than to slow down your code.

Comment: Yes, both ways worked.  In fairness, there was no difference in system.time() between the two arguments, but I appreciate simplicity wherever possible!

Comment: There won't be on something this size. Consider what which() does - it takes the logical vector generated by the %in%, turns it into indices and then uses those indices to subset the data. Since R allows subsetting using logical vectors directly, the which() is an unnecessary operation.

Comment: I disagree: `which` allow you to handle differently the case in which you have missing data (`NA`). In particular, if one weird `Data$Age` happens to be `NA`, your expression will return `NA`, while mine will return the mean of all other existing data... *So it is NOT meaningless to have this `which`.*. I don't believe that the slowing down is noticeable, too: did you benchmark that? :)